# how do i declare a matrix with 3 dimension in opencv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

i am new to opencv, i have an issue with opencv, want to declare this matrix `A = zeros (800,600,2)`
i did seaerch on opencv.org i found this type of declaration

```
     int dim2[3] = {800,600,2};
     Mat vv(3,dim2, CV_32F, Scalar::all(0));
```

but when debug with Qt it shows me an error with my for loop et the second line, so i thought that this is an issu with indeces and my declaration, here is my loop :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 800 ; i++)
        { for (int j = 0; j < 600; j++)
           {
           vv.at<double>(i,j,0) = - maxy + j * stepy;
           vv.at<double>(i,j,1) = - maxz + (801 - i) *stepz;
           }
        }
```

Comment: what error does it show?

Comment: when debug with Qt it shows me " segmentation fault " and point to this loop at the second line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a bug.

```
Mat vv(3,dim2, CV_32F, Scalar::all(0));
```

this creates a matrix of type float and here

```
vv.at<double>(i,j,0) = - maxy + j * stepy;
vv.at<double>(i,j,1) = - maxz + (801 - i) *stepz;
```

you call it as if it was a double matrix

either you to change the `32F`to a `64F`or change the `double` to `float`

Comment: thank you i have other errors but at least it work for this loop